# Circular animation to make UIImageView appear

Tags: ios, animation, uiimageview

I have a "circular" image, something like a pie chart. I would like a nice appearing animation, like when a pie chart fills itself from 0 to the value.

I usually use something like this when I want to animate views :

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: 3.0 
                      delay: 0.0 
                    options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut 
                 animations: ^ {
                             // The animation
                     } 
                 completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
                             // On completion
                     } ];
```

Is it possible to do the same thing for a circular animation ? I really have no idea on how to do that.

Thanks for any leads !

Note : iOS 5, storyboards, ARC, and all that stuff :)

---

Edit : for future discussion, the image looks like this :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, here it goes :)

First option (Easy one). You could use `UIImageView`'s `animationImages` property. Make `NSArray` with animation images (in your case, circular images those fill from 0 to full circle), set `animationDuration`, and call `[imageView startAnimating]` (I'm assuming that your `UIImageView` is `imageView`), and you can call `[imageView stopAnimating]` when process is done.

Second:
Check out this link http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/jpradialactivityindicator, I think that sample project does the almost same, as you are trying to do :)

Good Luck ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it fine if I have only like 10 images for example ? Will the animation seem continuous ? Or will it just display the images one by one with some fade effect ?

Comment: BTW, the methods are startAnimating and stopAnimating ;)

Comment: Sorry, my bad :), I think it should be fine with 10 images.. depends on animation duration and image size.

Comment: This is just basic way of animating images, for quality animations, see Nayan's answer :)

Comment: Thanks, I have to take some time to think about both solutions... I'll leave the question unanswered for now, I'll accept as soon as I implement one of the options :)

Comment: if you want to get the same result, you have to play with the source code of the second option. You could put circle in the beginning and end of the line that's being drawn.

Comment: Well, I found another one that looks even closer to what I want. I have to make sure I can do what I want with it though : http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/dacircularprogress

Comment: this one is also closer to that <http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/mac-os-x/controls/tspcircularprogressindicator>, it's developed for macos, though.

Comment: I think I'll go with DACircularProgress. Thanks for your help and you research !

Answer (score 2):

1) You can use **`CAShapeLayer`**

- You can achieve it by animating the strokeStart and strokeEnd properties. You could create the path for the full circle and use the strokeStart and strokeEnd properties to only stroke a certain part of the circle.

2) Also, you can refer to this tutorial : [Animating Pie Slices Using a Custom CALayer](http://blog.pixelingene.com/2012/02/animating-pie-slices-using-a-custom-calayer/)

Good Luck!!!

Comment: Thanks of the link. As I understand it, it's not using UIImages. I have to look a bit more into it, and I may use it if I can't find a way to do it with images. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: My problem with this solution is that it's not a complex pie chart I want to display, but more of a ring (see the edit of my question for the image). It might be way too complex for what I want to achieve...